# Recognise Computer Beeps After Launch

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, desktop-computer

When my computer is **booted** into Windows10 and runs normally, my **pc-speaker beeps**: "**two long times**" from times to times. I checked in Hardware monitor and the CPU, GPU and HDD temperatures look fine, I also checked the SMART statuses of my HDD and they look fine too.

Anyone any idea where that warning could stand for?

Comment: Maybe an installed product.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but how to figure out which one, I have tons of software and tools. Does Windows log the output to the pc-speaker?

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a specific piece of software doing it.

The best way I could think of to tackle this problem is to re-install windows and install each piece of software 1 by 1 run them for a period of time and isolate the problem.

Yea, I know it's a crappy solution. Maybe it's possible to create a computer script that will detect beeps and which piece of software caused the beep? But I doubt anything like that exists now.